# iPhone: Can .caf file be saved in Photo Library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to save .`caf` file into the **photo library** ?

In my app, User can record their sound and can upload it to the remote server. So I want to know that is it possible to save recorded voice file into photo library so user can view the previously recorded sound files and upload it ?

I've tried to save the .caf using `ALAssetsLibrary` by :-

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordTest.caf",DOCUMENTS_FOLDER]];
ALAssetsLibrary *lib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[lib writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:url completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
        if (error) 
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        } 
        else 
        {

        }
        }];
```

but it generates error...

> Error Domain=ALAssetsLibraryErrorDomain Code=-3302 "Invalid data"
>   UserInfo=0x184b80 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try with different
>   data, NSLocalizedFailureReason=There was a problem writing this asset
>   because the data is invalid and cannot be viewed or played.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid data, NSUnderlyingError=0x1834a0
>   "Invalid data"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And the answer is **`NO`**. It is not possible to store .caf file to Photo Library.